# Making my artificial intelligence project known? AI communities?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, logic, knowledge-management

I'm working on an artificial intelligence project, right now I am working on the subgoal of total "knowledge-representation". Expressing anything a human can express, basically.

I want to share my vision for the way to create artificial intelligence. Where is the place for that?

I have looked around, and not found a "lively community" for artificial intelligence. I've seen forums for specific AI related project. But that's not the right place. Doesn't seem right to go to attempto's forum and start talking about "how to create AI".

My project needs others to help. And so far, I have not found help.

Is there an "Artificial intelligence community"? Where I can talk about my language? And share my [vision](http://angelcog.org/stuff/vision/)?

If not, maybe I should start an AI community, myself? But again, I am an outsider, to the established AI researchers. I don't know what I'd need to do to get the right people attracted to my community.

Comment: Your website gave a great read. But you should consider either having black on white text or making the font more heavy. It's really straining to the eyes.

Comment: ziggystar, I DID consider that. Press the "lightbulb" button on my website. The website uses cookies so you only have to press it once. It should turn black and white. For what it's worth, I find white backgrounds to be eye straining and my eyes find dark backgrounds easier, but I know not everyone else's eyes/monitors/etc are the same as mine.

Answer (score 7):

AI is a highly active academia research field.

Publish academic papers about it. Through the paper, you'll get in contact with people interested by your stuff.

If it's not worth a paper or an academic article, then it's probably not worth a community either.

Comment: "If it's not worth a paper, then it's probably not worth a community either" that's quite a strong statement. Care to back that up? Where is the limit of "without a paper, theres no community". What communities do and what don't need papers behind them?

Comment: Considering it's about AI and "AI is a highly active academia research field.", I think the last statement is just realistic.

Comment: Thanks for your view flavius. I actually am not convinced that "without a paper the community is not worth it", but stackoverflow isn't for discussions, just questions and answers. And your response is still helpful, even if I am not convinced. The only thing that would convince me is a discussion. But discussions can have other outcomes. Your response deserves an upvote. I can't (new accounts cant upvote here).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [chatbots.org](https://www.chatbots.org) - they have an active community and although focused on chatbots, they have discussions covering many areas of AI.